# Checking process status from Python

Tags: python, linux

I am running on a Linux x86-64 system. From a Python (2.6)  script, I wish to periodically check whether a given process (identified by pid) has become "defunct"/zombie (this means that entry in the process table exists but the process is doing nothing). It would be also good to know how much CPU the process is consuming (similar to what 'top' command shows).

Can somebody give me some pointers on how I can get these in Python?

Comment: Run the `ps` command via subprocess.Popen(). Each line is a process and a Z in the STAT column means you've got a zombie. ps has a ton of parameters (`man ps`) and can give you a lot of information.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd use the [`psutil` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil):

```
import psutil

proc = psutil.Process(pid)
if proc.status() == psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE:
    # Zombie process!
```

Comment: `proc.get_cpu_times()`, `proc.get_cpu_percent(interval=1.0)`  to get CPU usage.

Answer (score 3):

you can get top result in python as below:

`linux`:

```
import sys, os
f = os.popen("top -p 1 -n 1", "r")
text = f.read()
print text
```

**update**

`windows`:

```
from os  import popen
from sys import stdin

ps = popen("C:/WINDOWS/system32/tasklist.exe","r")
pp = ps.readlines()
ps.close()

# wow, look at the robust parser!
pp.pop(0)       # blank line
ph = pp.pop(0)  # header line
pp.pop(0)       # ===

print ("%d processes reported." % len(pp))
print ("First process in list:")
print (pp[0])

stdin.readline()
```

Comment: assuming you are on an os that has it...(which OP is)